# draw 5 meter circle on google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to draw a 5-meter circle around a location, how can I map a 5-meter radius to pixels?

```
const radius = //5 meters
const myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  map,
  center: myCenter,
  radius: radius,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the radius of a circle is in meters, this should work:

```
const radius = 5; // meters
const myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  map,
  center: myCenter,
  radius: radius,
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/s1hec8r9/)

[image: screen shot of map with 5 meter circle]

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
  const radius = 5; // meters
  const myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.35,
  map: map,
  center: map.getCenter(),
  radius: radius,
});
  map.fitBounds(myCircle.getBounds())
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- 
     The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
     document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
     and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
     with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
    -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```